# Хранение html-тегов в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю на php новостную страничку. Некоторые html-теги используются при форматировании текста заметок. Как лучше поступить: записывать эти теги в базу данных вместе с текстом или использовать какие-нибудь символы или коды, которые потом заменять на теги при выводе? Как обычно поступают с этим в популярных cms и фреймворках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменять теги нет необходимости, но нужно аккуратно добавлять их в базу, чтобы избежать sql injection или ошибкок, если попадется, например, неэранированная кавычка. В идеале - используйте PDO prepared statement (если не используется ORM, в которой это уже предусмотрено).

Answer (score 2):

Моё мнение, не вижу смысла в замене тегов перед сохранением текста. Т.к. при отображении вам эти же теги и показывать нужно будет.

Я бы проверял только валидность данных перед тем как сохранить: что присутствуют только разрешённые теги, что все теги закрыты.

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу посредством bb-кодов. Редактирование с помощью [wysibb](http://www.wysibb.com/), при выводе - парсинг с помощью [jbbcode](http://jbbcode.com/)